# Dynamic PostgreSQL file using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, fs, pg-promise

I have a huge PostgreSQL file (300 lines) for creating a new client in my NodeJS application. (I use pg-promise.) I read the file and return the result with this simple code :

```
NewClient: function() {
    var sql = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/sql/creating_client.sql').toString();
    return db.any(sql);
}
```

I work great.

I have to manually change the declared variables in the file before processing the file.

For instance, my SQL file begin by declaring 20-30 variables.

*creating_client.sql :*

```
do $$
declare 
  clientname varchar(150) := 'Demo';
  clienthostname varchar(150) := 'demo';
  default_password varchar(100) := 'keyboardcat'; 
  ....
```

My question : Is there a way to inject dynamic variables from my javascript into the SQL file ?

Comment: [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) already does all that via [Query Files](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-files). See also: [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo), and [QueryFile API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/QueryFile.html).

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like that could work :

SQL

```
do $$
declare 
  clientname varchar(150) := '__clientname__';
  clienthostname varchar(150) := '__clienthostname__';
  default_password varchar(100) := '__default_password__'; 
  ....
```

Node

```
var myPassword = 'keyboardcat'
var sql = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/sql/creating_client.sql').toString();
sql.replace('__default_password__', myPassword);
```